# How to update SANE in raspberry to new version?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, sane

In the latest raspbian, after entering "sudo apt-get install sane", the version sane 1.0.25 is installed. I need to have version 1.0.27, which already supports my scanner. How can I install the latest version?

Comment: This is more a question for the raspberrypi part of stackexchange.  However, to give you some pointers: compile from sourcecode. Get it from http://www.sane-project.org/source.html.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have already tried to compile, but after running the scanimage -V command I get the verse: scanimage (sane-backends) 1.0.27; backend version 1.0.25
And unfortunately, scanimage still uses version 1.0.25 :(

Comment: de-install `sudo apt-get remove` all the sane-packages before you (re)compile and (re)install the backends. It may be that scanimage uses the lib in `/usr/lib` and 1.0.27 will probably be in `/usr/local/lib`